# Connect domain name to dyndns?

Tags: website, dns, dynamic-dns, dynamic-ip

I bought a domain name, `wafflegaze.com`. I have a DynDNS set up, `waffledns.endoftheinternet.org`. Can I make the former point to wherever the latter is currently pointing? I seem to only be able to add IP addresses to my DNS records.

UPDATE: I can make `www.wafflegaze.com` point to the DynDNS with a CNAME entry. Can I do this for the main domain name too?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot make `wafflegaze.com.` a CNAME, because it already contains the (required) SOA and NS records, and a CNAME cannot coexist with any other kind of a record.